# Google-Mock an already declared method

Tags: c++, googlemock

The syntax of `MOCK_METHOD` can be used inside a class definition:

```
class A {
    MOCK_METHOD0(f, void(void));
};
```

Is it possible to mock a method that has already been declared? What I want is to do something similar to:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class HelloTest {
    void f();
};

MOCK_METHOD0(HelloTest::f, void(void));
```

The idea is to put the class definition in an hpp file and then the mocks in a cpp file. In effect, my class definition with its methods' prototypes needs to be in common with other cpp files in my build chain and I don't want to use virtual functions.

Unfortunately, when I try to do what I wrote above, I get the following error on the line that contains `MOCK_METHOD0`:

```
error: ‘gmock0_HelloTest’ has not been declared
```

What does this error mean and is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, your `MOCK_METHOD0()` declaration must belong to a mock class, [under a `public` section](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-private-or-protected-methods). For instance, your code snippet:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class HelloTest {
    void f();
};

MOCK_METHOD0(HelloTest::f, void(void));
```

Should instead look like this:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class HelloTest {
    virtual void f();
};

class Mock_HelloTest : public HelloTest {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(f, void(void));
};
```

Now, you'll notice that I've changed `f()` to be virtual instead, since your use of `HelloTest::f` in `MOCK_METHOD0` requires `f()` to be virtual.

Since you don't want to use virtual functions, your only other option is to use what the Google Mock team calls [hi-perf dependency injection](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods). With this non-virtual approach, you'd have to create a separate mock class that doesn't inherit from `HelloTest`. You'd also need to templatize any code that currently uses `HelloTest` to switch between `HelloTest` in production and `Mock_HelloTest` in tests.

As an example, let's say you have the following function that calls `HelloTest::f()`:

```
void RunHelloTest() {
    HelloTest HT;
    HT.f();
}
```

You would set up your code snippet as follows:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class HelloTest {
    void f(); // <- f is no longer virtual
};

class Mock_HelloTest { // <- Mock_HelloTest no longer inherits from HelloTest
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(f, void(void));
};
```

And modify `RunHelloTest()` to accept a template type argument:

```
template <class HelloTestClass>
void RunHelloTest() {
    HelloTestClass HT;
    HT.f(); // <- will call HelloTest::f() or Mock_HelloTest::f()
}
```

With this setup, you'd call `RunHelloTest<HelloTest>()` in your production code, and `RunHelloTest<Mock_HelloTest>()` in your test code.

Comment: I forgot to add "public" in this example so you have a point. It doesn't fix my code though. I know about the templating method but it is not what I am looking for (it complicates a lot the code). Instead, I link the main code with the normal class implementation for the normal build, and with the mock for the test build. But to do that, I need those two cpps to share an hpp file to be included by the rest of the code. This is why I'm trying to separate the in-class methods' declaration from their definition with Google-Mock.

Comment: @Codoscope Unfortunately, Gmock requires the use of either virtual functions or templates (both of which I've outlined above). I feel your pain, but regardless of your code structure, you'd have to settle for either of those approaches.

Comment: Another approach however is to include the right file depending on whether I am building the test or the real program. That is what I am doing but I also wanted to know if it was still possible to mutualize the class declaration within an hpp file. So I guess that the answer to the second part of my question is just no. Do you know why I am getting this error though?